# How to change or edit the default thumbnail of an existing video in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, video

How can I change or edit the default thumbnail of an existing video? Ex: suppose I have a video of 5 minutes named *xyz*. In a list of videos, I want to show the *xyz*'s thumbnail image a specific image, I don't want to be depended on the default thumbnail.

To generate the thumb image, I used the bellow code block and it's working fine.

```
-(UIImage *)generateThumbImage : (NSURL *)filepath 
{

    NSURL *url = filepath;

    AVAsset *asset                          = [AVAsset assetWithURL:url];
    AVAssetImageGenerator *imageGenerator   = [[AVAssetImageGenerator alloc]initWithAsset:asset];
    CMTime time                             = [asset duration];
    time.value                              = 1000; //Time in milliseconds
    CGImageRef imageRef                     = [imageGenerator copyCGImageAtTime:time actualTime:NULL error:NULL];
    UIImage *thumbnail                      = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];

    imageGenerator.appliesPreferredTrackTransform = YES; //To fix the thumbnail orientation set
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);  // CGImageRef won't be released by ARC

    [thumbImage setImage:thumbnail] ;
    NSLog(@"Image set!!! %@", thumbnail);
    return thumbnail;
}
```

Comment: is there anyone to solve it?? or is this even possible to do so?? The iOS experts out there, please help me out.